# Few doubts on writing SQL queries

Tags: sql

Few questions i have here

- I always see some SQL written like below (not sure if i get it right)

  ```
  SELECT a.column_1, a.column_2 FROM table_name WHERE b.column_a = 'some value'
  ```

  i don't quite understand the SQL written in such way. Is it similar to using object in programming, where you can define an object and variables within the object? If it is, where is the definition of a and b for the SQL above (assuming i got the query right)?
- I want to make comparisons between 3 columns (say C1 C2 C3) in 3 different tables, say T1 T2 and T3. The condition is to get the values from the C1 in T1, that exists in C2 in T2, but not exists in C3 in T3. Both columns are practically the same, just that some might different or lesser records than the other columns in the other 2 tables, and i want to know what the differences are. Is the query below the right way to do it?

  ```
  select distinct C1 from T1
  and (C1) not in (select C2 from T2)
  and (C1) in (select C3 from T3)
  order by C1;
  ```

  And is it possible to extend the condition if i want to include more tables into comparison using the query above?
- If i were to customize the query above into something similar to the first question, is the query below the right way to do it?

  ```
  select a.C1 from T1 a
  and (a.C1) not in (select b.C2 from T2 b)
  and (a.C1) in (select c.C3 from T3 c)        
  order by a.C1;
  ```
- What are the advantanges of writing query in object way (like above), compared to writing it in traditional way? I feel like even if you define a table name as a variable, the variable only can be used within the query where it is defined, and cannot be extended to the other queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the first point is a and b are "table aliases" (shortcut reference to the table(s) involved in THAT query) e.g.

```
SELECT a.column_1, a.column_2 
FROM table_name_a a  ------------------------------- table alias a defined here
INNER JOIN table_name_b b -------------------------- table alias b defined here
      ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.column_a = 'some value'
```

Your second query has a syntax issue: You need `WHERE` as shown in uppercase. It also has and performance implications. Distinct adds effort to a query, using IN() is really a syntax shortcut for a series of ORs (it might not scale well). But with the syntax it is valid.

```
select distinct C1 
from T1
WHERE (C1) not in (select C2 from T2)
and (C1) in (select C3 from T3)
order by C1;
```

Yes (with performance reservations) you could add more tables into that comparison.

You introduce table aliases, done correctly, into your third query - but there is no real advantage in that query structure. Aside from just making code more convenient, aliases serve to distinguish between items that would be ambiguous. In my first query above `ON a.id = b.id` shows possible ambiguity in that 2 tables both have a field of the same name. Prefixing the field name by a table or table alias solves that ambiguity.

Comment: Yah forgot the WHERE clause because i edited it from the original query, which has a WHERE clause on it.

Comment: it happens (often); I have trouble typing seelct :)

Comment: please note the answer by Krishnraj Rana below who points out use of |NOT| EXISTS as alternatves to IN()

Answer (score 2):

For your first point.

> I always see some SQL written like below (not sure if i get it right)

```
SELECT a.column_1, a.column_2 FROM table_name WHERE b.column_a = 'some value'
```

This query is wrong. It should be like this -

```
SELECT a.column_1, a.column_2 
FROM table_name a INNER JOIN --(There might be another join also like left join etc..)
table_name b
ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.column_a = 'some value'
```

so you noted in the above query that a and b are just table alias. Well, there are some cases you must use them, like when you need to join to the same table twice in one query.

For the second point. you can also do it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT C1 FROM T1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT C2 FROM T2 t2 where t2.C2 = t1.C1)
AND WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT C3 FROM T3 t3 where t3.C3 = t1.C1)
ORDER BY C1;
```

Personally I prefer aliases, and unless I have a lot of tables they tend to be single letter ones.

Comment: thanks for point out the use of EXISTS as (good) alternatives for IN()

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the table aliases in the FROM clause, so:

```
SELECT a.column_1, b.column_1
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

It should be possible to make your comparisons in the way you have written your query above, however it is also possible to make aliasing easier by using subqueries in the FROM clause ie:

```
SELECT tab1.id, tab2.id, tab3.id
FROM table1 as tab1,
(select * from table2)as tab2,
(select * from table3)as tab3
```

This way you can choose any columns from any of the tables using tab1.xxx etc. and then use the WHERE clause to say NOT IN tab2.column_1 etc...

Comment: Yah forgot the WHERE clause because i edited it from the original query, which has a WHERE clause on it. Anyway i see you're defining all the table aliases for all tables in one line? But the table you defined must match with the column you defined in the SELECT right? Can't i just define the whole table aliases together in FROM statement, even if some columns of the other tables are used in the later part of the query?

Comment: SQL in effect works backwards, so anything defined in the FROM and WHERE is worked-out before SELECT, so if you work out your aliases in FROM first, it is then easier to choose your SELECT elements (especially in SQL Management Studio with autocomplete)

Comment: Meaning that instead of the traditional SELECT FROM, i can do FROM SELECT which allows me to define all the table aliases, and the respective columns further down the query?

Comment: no sorry...the Format is still the same ie.
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE x=y ORDER BY 1` it is just how a query is handled by SQL server, so populating the data sources in the FROM clause and then moving back up to the SELECT statement can be advantageous

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this one so don't quote me, but ill give it my best shot.

I think that when alias' are used it is because if you don't use them your statement can he huge and hard to understand, here is a comparison with two SQL query's, one using alias' and the other without:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE c.CustomerName="Around the Horn" AND c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID;
```

Without:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerName="Around the Horn" AND Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID;
```

As you can see one looks much easier to understand and read than the other and makes your query's much smaller.

Aliases can be useful when:

- There are more than one table involved in a query
- Functions are used in the query
- Column names are big or not very readable
- Two or more columns are combined together

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Thanks for the comparison. I see that the table aliases are good for displaying joint columns from multiple tables. So i take it that table aliases defined in FROM statement must match with the columns stated in SELECT statement? Coz i was thinking if its possible to do like, just define whole tables in one FROM statement, altho i'm not using all the tables defined in my SELECT statement, that would be great.